# Using a custom filter with a lot of tags throws an error on refreshing the page

Tags: bug, filtering, custom-filters

Steps to reproduce:

1. Setup a custom filter with a big number of tags. The ones I currently have for testing is

> javascript or typescript or flowtype or node.js or functional-programming or lodash or underscore.js or ramda.js or knockout.js or jasmine or mocha.js or jestjs or chai or regex or jquery or lambda or recursion or cyclomatic-complexity or complexity-theory zzzz

I do not think the "Sorted by" makes a difference here but I have "Newest" selected.
I also do not think the "Filter by" makes a difference. I chose none of the options.

[image: Custom filter using the above quoted string as filter for tags.]

For completeness, I have called it "test" but I do not think the name matters.

Note that the **zzzz** tag does not exist. I use it for padding.

2. Open the custom filter from the side bar. This *works* and you get questions filtered by the given criteria. Live reloading also works fine - you get notification for new questions and clicking it loads them:

[image: Screenshot of the list of question with a notification about new activity on top.]

3. Refresh the page.

**Expected result:** everything works like going at step 2 again - questions are loaded and filtered.

**Actual result:** An error page shows up with the following text:

> Bad Request - Invalid URL
>
> HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.

[image: Screenshot of the page with the message from above]

Tested on:
Firefox 89.0.2 on Windows 10
Chrome  89.0.4389.90 on Windows 10
Firefox 89 on Manjaro Linux
Chromium 90.0.4430.212 on Manjaro Linux
wget and curl on Manjaro Linux
Brave 1.26.74, Chromium 91.0.4472.124 on Android
Firefox 89.1.1 on Android

Happens both on my normal landline as well as a separate mobile network.

---

Additional information:

- Here is a direct link to test this filter (shows Bad Request): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+or+typescript+or+flowtype+or+node.js+or+functional-programming+or+lodash+or+underscore.js+or+ramda.js+or+knockout.js+or+jasmine+or+mocha.js+or+jestjs+or+chai+or+regex+or+jquery+or+lambda+or+recursion+or+cyclomatic-complexity+or+complexity-theory+zzzz

  The filter I showed seems to be exactly at the edge of where things break. *The following link works* (last padding tag is changed from **zzzz** to **zzz**):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+or+typescript+or+flowtype+or+node.js+or+functional-programming+or+lodash+or+underscore.js+or+ramda.js+or+knockout.js+or+jasmine+or+mocha.js+or+jestjs+or+chai+or+regex+or+jquery+or+lambda+or+recursion+or+cyclomatic-complexity+or+complexity-theory+zzz
- Long filters used to work yesterday. I have a filter I use daily and only noticed the problem this morning (2021-07-15) around 05:00 UTC.
- The failure seems closely related to the tag filter. Removing an **or** operator can also produce a working link, however, the filtering expression is now different (no "or" means an implicit "and").
- It is most definitely not the *amount* of tags involved, it is the literal length of the filter string. Adding a tag like

  ```
  [ecmascript-*]
  ```

  will auto expand to

  ```
  [ecmascript-6] or [ecmascript-5] or [ecmascript-2016] or [ecmascript-next] or [ecmascript-2017] or [ecmascript-harmony] or [ecmascript-2020] or [ecmascript-3] or [ecmascript-intl] or [ecmascript-2018] or [ecmascript-4] or [ecmascript-2021] or [ecmascript-2019]
  ```

  But that does not seem to matter: this link works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+or+typescript+or+flowtype+or+node.js+or+functional-programming+or+lodash+or+underscore.js+or+ramda.js+or+knockout.js+or+jasmine+or+mocha.js+or+jestjs+or+chai+or+regex+or+jquery+or+lambda+or+recursion+or+cyclomatic-complexity+or+ecmascript-*+zzzzzzzz

  This does not (extra **z** at the end): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+or+typescript+or+flowtype+or+node.js+or+functional-programming+or+lodash+or+underscore.js+or+ramda.js+or+knockout.js+or+jasmine+or+mocha.js+or+jestjs+or+chai+or+regex+or+jquery+or+lambda+or+recursion+or+cyclomatic-complexity+or+ecmascript-*+zzzzzzzzz
- It seems like the problem is around 262 characters of a filter string in the URL:

  Working (261 characters):

  ```
  javascript+or+typescript+or+flowtype+or+node.js+or+functional-programming+or+lodash+or+underscore.js+or+ramda.js+or+knockout.js+or+jasmine+or+mocha.js+or+jestjs+or+chai+or+regex+or+jquery+or+lambda+or+recursion+or+cyclomatic-complexity+or+complexity-theory+zzz

  javascript+or+typescript+or+flowtype+or+node.js+or+functional-programming+or+lodash+or+underscore.js+or+ramda.js+or+knockout.js+or+jasmine+or+mocha.js+or+jestjs+or+chai+or+regex+or+jquery+or+lambda+or+recursion+or+cyclomatic-complexity+or+ecmascript-*+zzzzzzzz
  ```

  Not working (262 characters and above):

  ```
  javascript+or+typescript+or+flowtype+or+node.js+or+functional-programming+or+lodash+or+underscore.js+or+ramda.js+or+knockout.js+or+jasmine+or+mocha.js+or+jestjs+or+chai+or+regex+or+jquery+or+lambda+or+recursion+or+cyclomatic-complexity+or+complexity-theory+zzzz

  javascript+or+typescript+or+flowtype+or+node.js+or+functional-programming+or+lodash+or+underscore.js+or+ramda.js+or+knockout.js+or+jasmine+or+mocha.js+or+jestjs+or+chai+or+regex+or+jquery+or+lambda+or+recursion+or+cyclomatic-complexity+or+ecmascript-*+zzzzzzzzz
  ```
- [Also reported here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409167/longer-urls-no-longer-work)

## As of close to a week now (2021-08-03), I cannot reproduce this problem.

Comment: I did some [high-level research on this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408952/support-wild-cards-for-tags-in-custom-filter/408968#408968) really recently; I'm not sure that the limit is actually around 262 characters, since that first link works fine for me, and you can have both [searches](https://tinyurl.com/3njh32b7) (79 tags + wildcard, 1,750 characters) and [savable filters](https://tinyurl.com/yvrmavum) (49 tags + wildcard, 1135 characters) with much larger lengths than what you've provided (apologies for the link shorteners, these URLs are *huge*).

Comment: The only hard limit I found for sure with filters was a system one on tag quantity; a filter will only successfully save with 50 tags maximum, but wildcards only count as one tag.

Comment: @zcoop98 "*that first link works fine for me*" I get Bad Request in both Firefox and Chrome on Windows. The two tinyurl links you have also give me Bad Request. Note that *saving a custom filter* and *loading a custom filter* work for me. When loading, it's actually navigating to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?uqlId=44345` (so, has the ID for the custom filter) which then expands to the full filter string in the URL. But going to the URL with the filter string in place fails.

Comment: I wonder what's different on my end then, hm... ([Screenshot of search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOyEN.png)) I am on Chrome v91, but it'd be a little silly if that made the difference.

Comment: [Tag:status-no-repro]

Comment: @zcoop98 dunno. This did work for me yesterday. I've also seen it on two different machines. If there is something on my end, it must be related to my connection - the two machines share it. I'll also try it on Linux now. It could also be caching, I suppose. Not sure how. Or *maybe* going through different network paths - like me getting the short stick for some load balancer or something.

Comment: @VLAZ you mind trying on a mobile connection? 4/5G for example

Comment: @Luuklag not at all. Give me a moment to boot up the Linux laptop I have and test it there first. I'll then try my phone and also try tethering the PC to the phone.

Comment: @Luuklag OK tried it. Same thing happens on both my desktops (Windows), on my laptop (Linux), my phone (Android) and it's the same whether I use mobile connection or normal landline.

Comment: When I first ran into the Bad Request error, I made the assumption that the error was server-side, because SE has to interpret the request sent over by client; but if some long URLs work for one user and not for others, then maybe it's actually client-side? But that doesn't sound like it makes much sense... that said, I don't have *any* idea as to why the limit on SE's side would be different from user to user though, that'd be super weird.

Comment: @zcoop98 clients connecting through different network routes is going to be my next guess. Doing `nslookup stackoverflow.com` I get 151.101.65.69; 151.101.193.69; 151.101.129.69; 151.101.1.69; might be those machines that are a problem. Maybe they mangle the request if it's too long. I just tried each and they all gave me Bad Request.

Comment: @VLAZ Do you mean `tracert stackoverflow.com`? `nslookup` will give the IPs associated with SO's domain. `tracert` will show all the steps between your connection and their server.

Comment: @zcoop98 no, I do mean `nslookup` - it did give me 4 different addresses that will answer when trying to reach stackoverflow.com. I then tried `wget` with a non-working URL multiple times until I saw a response from each of the machines. All of them returned Bad Request. Using the one character shorter URL worked, however.

Comment: Just ruled out another thing: I downloaded Chromium 89, the same version you listed in the post, and I can access that search link just fine, so it doesn't appear to be a browser version thing, on Win10 at least.

Comment: This also affects the API, apparently. I get the same error if the URL is long.

Comment: Just before I have verified and this issue has been resolved.

Comment: @Arulkumar I'm still getting the issue here.

Comment: @VLAZ Oh :( Can you check once after "Ctrl + F5".

Comment: @Arulkumar yep. I still get the same, even if I clear the cache.

Comment: **VOTING TO CLOSE MY QUESTION**: I can no longer reproduce it. It's been about a week and it is working correctly. I delayed the closure to make sure it won't randomly regress.